# Help first-time posting users construct a good question

Tags: feature-request

I see a lot of good questions by first-time posters who have challenges/problems/issues (at low and/or high degree) but their English isn't always good, they have difficulties explaining themselves, and their posts are not well-structured at all.

When you as a user go to the Ask Question page you have the box on your right-hand side which guides you on how to use formatting and how tags work - but not on how to construct a good well-structured question.

Yes, we do have the [How do I ask a good question?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page but that requires users to first go to the [Help center](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help) to find that helpful page.

I want to suggest that we highlight that page on the Ask Question page for first-time posters.
Not just as a box on the right side but as a popup the first time they create a post and then afterwards it can be put as a link in the box on the right-hand side.

Comment: Since this is infrastructure, you should repost this to Meta.SO for better coverage/discussion. Its worth mentioning it was originally from SPSE (for context).